# What is the purpose of app_label

Tags: python, django-models

Unfortunately I lost the specific error message I got but it was along these lines - Django model "doesn't declare an explicit app_label".

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/) says - If a model is defined outside of an application in INSTALLED_APPS, it must declare which app it belongs to. Unfortunately I don't understand the documentation. I am trying to pin point the specific reason why I need to include `app_label='hotel'`.

Here is my **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   


    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
  
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',


    #our apps

    'hotel',
    'marketing',
    'orders',
    'products',
    
]
```

Here is **models.py**

```
import random
import os
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
from django.conf import settings


from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL



    
def get_filename_ext(filepath):
    print("get_filename_ext")
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    return name, ext

#  name 'upload_image_path' is not defined
def upload_image_path(instance, filename):
    print("upload_image_path")
    new_filename = random.randint(1,3910209312)
    name, ext = get_filename_ext(filename)
    final_filename = '{new_filename}{ext}'.format(new_filename=new_filename, ext=ext)
    return "Hotel/{new_filename}/{final_filename}".format(
        new_filename=new_filename, 
        final_filename=final_filename
        )
   


class RoomType(models.Model):
    Room_Type = (
        ('Single','Single'),
        ('Double','Double'),
        ('Family','Family'),
        ('Dormitory','Dormitory'),
        ('F.Dormitory','Female Dormitory'),
        )
    HotelName           = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    RoomType            = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, choices=Room_Type)
    Image               = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    Price               = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=39.99)
    Quantity            = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'hotel'
```

Comment: You should not use an `app_label` unless there is a reason why you want to specify a different `app_label` for that model.

Comment: I used an app_label when I got this error message - Django model "doesn't declare an explicit app_label"

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have the specific error message. I will try and recreate the error.